# Migrate WSUS from 2003 to 2012 R2 core

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

We have WSUS 3.2 running on Windows Server 2003 (with SP2), and we're looking to migrate to Windows Server Core 2012 R2.  I've done a fair amount of internet searching, and all of the results I found seem to assume that the destination server has a GUI.  We're specifically looking to migrate to Windows Server **Core**.  For the database, my preference would be WID because we only have about 200 clients.  Is this a feasible task?  [Microsoft's Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852352.aspx) mentions using SSMS to backup the database on the source server and restore it to the destination server.  But since that isn't an option on server core, is there a CLI or Powershell alternative?  Is there anyone out there with experience doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to complete this project by installing SQL Express 2014 on the server (see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/852300/can-sql-express-be-installed-on-server-core/852313#852313) for that discussion).  I was then able to connect to the database using SSMS on another computer in order to complete the database steps.