# Can SQL Express be installed on Server Core?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I've been searching nearly an hour for a definitive answer and I've come up empty so far.  Can anyone confirm, one way or another, whether SQL **Express** (version 2012 or later) can be installed on Windows Server Core 2012 R2?

I tried it myself with command line parameters, and I got an error message that the parameter "userName" was missing.  I couldn't find any documentation that made reference to such a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Microsoft, it can:

- [Install SQL Server 2016 on Server Core | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-on-server-core)
- [Hardware and Software Requirements for SQL Server 2014 | Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx)

Not all SQL Server features are supported though.

To install SQL Server Engine only, hiding all dialogs whilst showing the progress log, with Mixed Mode authentication with the `MyServer\Administrator` being an administrator and setting the "`sa` password to `MySekretPasswyrd`, with TCP/IP enabled and specifying the product ID of `ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY`:

```
Setup.exe /QS /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT=”NT Authority\System” /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=”MyServer\Administrator” /AGTSVCACCOUNT=”NT AUTHORITY\Network Service” /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="MySekretPasswyrd" /TCPENABLED=1 /PID=ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=1
```

If you are installing several database servers, it might make more sense for you to put most of these parameters into a configuration file and use that during installation.

See [Install SQL Server from the Command Prompt | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-2016-from-the-command-prompt) for more on the command line parameters

As for your error, is  it possible you didn't specify a system administrator account at all?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to mark Pak's answer correct, for confirming that it can indeed be done.  I tried a few more times before finally hitting upon the correct combination of parameters.  Here's the one that worked:

```
Setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT="<Domain>\Administrator" /SQLSVCPASSWORD="<password>" /TCPENABLED=1 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

This was for SQL 2014 Express on Windows Server Core 2012 R2

Comment: Glad to be of help.